# Run puppeteer before tests and pass page to tests

Tags: typescript, puppeteer, ava

I want to start a puppeteer instance in **ava** before all tests and pass the page to all tests, so I can work with that active puppeteer instance. I'm using TypeScript and have followed these guides:

- https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/docs/recipes/puppeteer.md
- https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/docs/recipes/typescript.md

The problem is, that I don't understand how to pass these things between them. Ava gives me a TypeScript error, which sounds reasonable but I don't know how I should build the logic to get this working:

```
test/current.spec.ts:41:50 - error TS2345: Argument of type '(t: TestExecutionContext, bp: number, expected: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OneOrMoreMacros<any, {}>'
```

currrent.spec.ts:

```js
import path from 'path'
import test, { ExecutionContext } from 'ava'
import runBrowserWithPage from './_withPage'
import { Page } from 'puppeteer'

interface TestExecutionContext extends ExecutionContext {
  context: {
    page: Page
  }
}

const url = 'file://' + path.resolve(__dirname, '../docs/index.html')

const widths = [575, 576, 768, 992, 1200]

test.before(runBrowserWithPage, async (t: TestExecutionContext, page: Page) => {
  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'load' })
  t.context.page = page
})

// test.beforeEach(async ({ context }: TestExecutionContext) => {
//   await context.page.reload()
// })

async function currentMacro(t: TestExecutionContext, bp: number, expected: string) {
  await t.context.page.setViewport({ width: bp, height: 800 })
  await t.context.page.screenshot({ path: `assets/${bp}.png` })

  const current: any = await t.context.page.evaluate(() => {
    // @ts-ignore
    const Breakpoint = new Boobreaks()
    return Breakpoint.current() // return breakpoint alias
  })

  t.is(current, expected)
}

// test('Boobreaks should be loaded', async (t: TestExecutionContext) => {
// })

test('Boobreaks should return the alias for xs', currentMacro, widths[0], 'xs')
```

_withPage.ts

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'

export default async function withPage(t: any, run: any) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  try {
    await run(t, page)
  } finally {
    await page.close()
    await browser.close()
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? :)

Comment: He wants to run puppeteer before running all tests on ava. But he is not able to do so. Though I don't see what exact issue he faced.

Comment: Ah, sorry @ThomasDondorf. I have edited my post. It simply does not work. I just wanna know how this should be done correctly. I read that this is the way but AVA is cloning the context before passing to the tests which in this case would destroy the puppeteer instance, does it? And of course there is something wrong with my way of using the ExecutionContext..